# Extra SSL Certificate For Database Server?

Tags: security, ssl

I have three servers:

1. Web-Server
2. Database Server
3. Database Replication Server

In the upcoming days, I am going to order a SSL certificate for the Web-Server to deliver the data encrypted to the client. This SSL certificate should be enough to also transport the data encrypted to the Database Server.

However, I am also in need of an encrypted connection in regards to the Database Replication Server.

Is it possible to set up the exact same SSL certificate on the Database Server/Database Replication Server? Or will I have to order an extra SSL certificate?

---

**OS**: Ubuntu Linux

**DBMS**: postgreSQL

**Reason for encrypting data**: Securing data, avoiding MITM attacks, ... (propably every reason for SSL encryption).

**WAN**: I have three independent vServers. I might move the DB-Servers into a VLAN (intranet) later on but at the moment all servers are running independently at one hoster's network.

Comment: More detail needed - why are you encrypting the database connection? What database engine are you using? What OS? Is your database connection across a WAN?

Comment: Why would these matter? He needs them encrypted, and wants to know how many certs he will need

Comment: How do you know? The OP hasn't given any details.

Comment: I know he needs them encrypted because he says so in his question. (The sentence beginning "However")

Comment: Updated the question. Why do OS and DBMS matter?

Comment: The last edit made is the killer piece of info. Encryption on a secure LAN is overkill 90% of the time and will add CPU overhead for every byte of data you want to encrypt.

Comment: How do you know that it's a secure LAN?

Comment: Even if the servers are in the same network of the hoster I would still prefer to transfer the data between these servers securely. As a server administrator I shouldn't trust anyone, not even my hoster.

Comment: Since you're in control of both the webserver and the database server, you can create your own self-signed certificate for the communication between them instead of paying for one.

Comment: What would be the difference between using a self-signed SSL certificate and using IPSec? Any benefits for either alternative in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use SSL certificate for any of your server whether it is Web-Server, Database Server or Database Replication Server.

If you buy a **Comodo SSL certificate** then you will be allows to install SSL on any number of server.

For **Symantec & Thawte** SSL certificate, you need to purchase license for each single server.

Comment: On your listed website "cheapsslsecurity.com", the GeoTrust products are also listed as having "unlimited server licenses"

Comment: Why would that matter? The SSL certificate is still bound to one domain and that domain points to one server only.